# What is the purpose of using memory stream in the C standard library?

Tags: c, io, memorystream, c-standard-library

In the C standard library, what is the purpose of using a memory stream (as created for an array via `fmemopen()`)? How is it compared to manipulating the array directly?

Comment: Lets say you have a function which takes a `FILE*` as argument, and you want the output it writes but in an in-memory buffer instead of written to a file on disk. You could open a file and have the function write to it, and then read the contents of the file into memory. But wouldn't it be much simpler if you could create a `FILE*` from a memory buffer instead?

Comment: Oh and note that [`fmemopen`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fmemopen.html) is not a standard C function, but part of the POSIX standard.

Comment: I can't find the document right now, but there was a written proposal for the inclusion of this and other functions in POSIX 2008 that explains the motivations (at least the ones the committee seems to have been convinced by) very well. A good answer should cite it.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Thanks. I asked about the comparison between using memory stream and directly manipulating the array in memory. I didn't mention using a file.

Comment: Then no there's really no difference. Why use `fmemopen` and e.g. `fprintf` instead of plain `snprintf` directly (for example)? The difference comes with dealing with functions that deal with `FILE*`. The point of `fmemopen` is to make it easier to have a common interface for writing to or reading from a generic destination/source, no matter if it's memory or files.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude  Why to "have a common interface for writing to or reading from a generic destination/source, no matter if it's memory or files"?

Comment: Because abstraction and common interfaces are good principles? But that strays from your question for which the answer could realistically only be: It depends. Do you need to call a function which write to (or reads from) a `FILE *`? If not then there's really no need to use `fmemopen` or similar functions, just use the array or buffer directly. Otherwise you'll be glad there is such functions (*if* they are available for your system).

Answer (score 3):

This is very similar to using the `std::stringstream` in C++, which allows you to write to a string (including `'\0'` characters) and then use the string the way you'd like.

The idea is that we have many functions at our disposal, such as `fprintf()`, which can be used to write data to a stream in a formatted way. All those functions can be used with a memory based file without any need for further changes anywhere else than the `fopen()` to `fmemopen()`.

So if you want to create a string which requires many `fprintf()`, using that function to generate the string in memory is extremely useful. The `snprintf()` could also be used if you just need one *quick* conversion.

Similarly, you can of course use `fread()` and `fwrite()` and the like. If you need to create a file which requires a lot of seeking and it's not that big that it can easily fit in memory, then it's going to go a lot faster. Once done, you can save the results to disk.